# Не работает метод download_file в telegram bot api local server

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, telegram

Появилась проблема с загрузкой файлов через бота.

Если кратко идея была в том чтобы отправлять боту видео, а он его кидает в папку на ПК.
Когда его сделал он вроде работал но появилась другая проблема ограничение в загрузку в 20 мб.
После чего развернул локально bot api на пк, все нормально в консоли отобразило.

Но теперь когда я отправляю файл боту он пишет

```
telebot.apihelper.ApiHTTPException:
A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful.
The server returned HTTP 404 Not Found. Response body:
[b'{"ok":false,"error_code":404,"description":"Not Found"}']
```

и не грузит его в нужную папку.

При всем при этом если зайти в папку самого бота на сервере там этот файл будет с названием file_0.mp4.
Также GetFile возвращает нормальный file_path и file_id

Подскажите как это можно исправить?

```
def step2(message):

    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, """randomtext """)
    file_info = bot.get_file(message.video.file_id)
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)

    src = dir + message.video.file_name;

    with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:

        new_file.write(downloaded_file)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, step3)
```

Comment: Можешь показать исправленую функцию?

Comment: а можешь поделится кодом, как ты это сделал в итоге?

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем, сам разобрался боту не нужно загружать файл через bot.download_file так как если работает local api server, можно просто обратится к файлу через file_id, и все будет работать